# compare ethtool output of Supported/Advertised link mode

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to capture the output of "Supported link modes:" and "Advertised link modes:" of ethtool to see if my card has higher support but doesn't support by switch side. so, I was trying to do an awk or sed to capture just the output of mode list but I couldn't find a way to just capture that part to be able to compare. any idea?

```
ethtool em1
Settings for em1:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   1000baseKX/Full
                                10000baseKR/Full
                                25000baseCR/Full
                                25000baseKR/Full
                                25000baseSR/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: None BaseR
        Advertised link modes:     1000baseKX/Full
                                10000baseKR/Full
                                25000baseCR/Full
                                25000baseKR/Full
                                25000baseSR/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: None
        Speed: 10000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000004 (4)
                               link
        Link detected: yes
```

Here is the expected output:

```
Supported link modes:      1000baseKX/Full
                                10000baseKR/Full
                                25000baseCR/Full
                                25000baseKR/Full
                                25000baseSR/Full
Advertised link modes:    1000baseKX/Full
                                10000baseKR/Full
                                25000baseCR/Full
                                25000baseKR/Full
                                25000baseSR/Full
```

What I was planning to do with this output is that to compare the advertised link with a supported link if the advertised link is less than supported

Here is what I came up with for my solution. I am sure this can be improved:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the interface name
iface=$1

# Get the supported link modes
supported=$(ethtool $iface  | awk '/Supported link modes:/{mode=$NF; getline; while(/[[:space:]]+[0-9]+/){mode=mode" "$NF;getline}} END{print mode}')

# Get the advertised link modes
advertised=$(ethtool $iface  | awk '/Advertised link modes:/{mode=$NF; getline; while(/[[:space:]]+[0-9]+/){mode=mode" "$NF;getline}} END{print mode}')

# Compare the supported and advertised link modes
if [ "$supported" == "$advertised" ]; then
  echo "The supported and advertised link modes match."
else
  echo "The supported and advertised link modes do not match."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the expected output in your question, nor was it clear if you wanted to output the difference between the 2 blocks, so here's what I think you might be asking for, using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
    if ( s = index($0,":") ) {
        tag = substr($0,1,s-1)
        val = substr($0,s+1)
        sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",val)
    }
    tag2val[tag] = (tag in tag2val ? tag2val[tag] ORS : "") val
}

END {
    print "Supported link modes:"
    print tag2val["Supported link modes"]

    print ""

    print "Advertised link modes:"
    print tag2val["Advertised link modes"]
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Supported link modes:
1000baseKX/Full
1000baseKX/Full
1000baseKX/Full
1000baseKX/Full
1000baseKX/Full
1000baseKX/Full

Advertised link modes:
1000baseKX/Full
1000baseKX/Full
1000baseKX/Full
1000baseKX/Full
1000baseKX/Full
1000baseKX/Full
```